# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python

I am trying to do a project in python. I'm getting an error in the line

> `s+=line`
>
> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'`

Here is the function called `testIfCorrect`:

```
def testIfCorrect(world, x, y):
    s=0
    for line in world:
        s+=line
        print("ligne",line)
        if(s > 2):
            return False
    for i in range(x):
        if(sum(returnColumn(world, i)) > 2):
            return False
    for j in range(x):
        for k in range(y):
            if(j == k):
                pass
            else:
                if(world[j] == world[k]):
                    return False
                if(returnColumn(world, j) == returnColumn(world ,k)):
                    return False

def returnColumn(array, column):
    return [col[column] for col in array]
```

Where is the error?

Comment: What does `line` contain? What did you expect to happen instead? `s` is an integer (`s=0`), but clearly `line` is a string, presumably because `world` is a list of strings or a file, or perhaps one string.

Comment: How do you call `testIfCorrect`. Can you tell the parameters for it. I think `world` is a list of lists. Please confirm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In

```
s=0
for line in world:
    s+=line
```

Here `s` is an int and `word`is 2D List. So, In  `for line in world`, `line` is a `1D List`. It is impossible to add a `List` into a `int` type. Here, `s+=line` in **incorrect**

So, In `s+=line`, you can replace **s+=sum(line)**. I think you have found your answer.

Try this:

```
s=0
for line in world:
    s+=sum(line)
```

Comment: how I could do this ?